# How can i upload image with ajax in codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to upload image with jQuery and ajax function, and how can I fetch all details of image file, like in php we use `$_FILE()`

Here is my code

**JS**

```
$("#uploadimg" ).click(function() {
     $( "#file" ).click();
});

$( "#file" ).change(function(e) {
    var file=$('#file').val();
    alert(file);
    die();
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost/JSG/blog/uploadimg',
        secureuri:false,
        type: "POST",
        fileElementId:'image',
        dataType: 'text',
        data:{ file: file },
        cache: true,
        success: function (data){
            alert(data);
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function uploadimg()
{
    $var = $_POST['file'];
    print_r($var);
    if($this->input->post('file')) {
        $config['upload_path'] = 'upload'; 
        $config['file_name'] = $var;
        $config['overwrite'] = 'TRUE';
        $config["allowed_types"] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
        $config["max_size"] = '1024';
        $config["max_width"] = '400';
        $config["max_height"] = '400';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $this->data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
            print_r( $this->data['error']);
        } else {
            print_r("success");
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Blog Title:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Upload image:</label>
        <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assest/img/blank.png" alt="Blank image" id="uploadimg" class="img-thumbnail">
        <input style="display:none" id="file" value=" " type="file" class="file" data-show-preview="false">
    </div>
</form>
```

**Response**

> C:\fakepath\Koala.jpg You did not select a file to upload.

Please help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can to use FormData api in html5.

Your form must be:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" name="formname" id="formname"  method="post" action="">
```

Then jquery:

```
function uploadImage() {

    if (typeof FormData !== 'undefined') {

        // send the formData
        var formData = new FormData( $("#formID")[0] );

        $.ajax({
            url : baseUrl + 'uploadImage',  // Controller URL
            type : 'POST',
            data : formData,
            async : false,
            cache : false,
            contentType : false,
            processData : false,
            success : function(data) {
                successFunction(data);
            }
        });

    } else {
       message("Your Browser Don't support FormData API! Use IE 10 or Above!");
    }   
}
```

Then in the controller you will get the files in `$_FILES` array.

Comment: When i'm using $_FILES in my controller his throw [Object FileData]

there is some problem ..Please help

Comment: i'm not getting actual value how can i use full file path.

Comment: you have to check - $_FILES ['name'] where 'name' is the name of the input type=file. Also you have to give name attribute to all inputs. Use var_dump() to see the infos.

Comment: @John, I just want to know why you used [0] in $("#formID")[0])?

Answer (score 0):

In the view where you are displaying form:

add attribute: `enctype=multipart/form-data`

Or,

If you are creating a form with form helper:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('blog/uploadimg');?>
```

Comment: no i'm not using form tag.
Here is my view->>>>>

 <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Upload image:</label>
            <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assest/img/blank.png" alt="Blank image" id="uploadimg" class="img-thumbnail">
            <input style="display:none" id="file" value=" " type="file" class="file" data-show-preview="false">
          </div>

Answer (score 0):

You can get seamless functionality if you use this plugin (well written) in javascript.

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

To Upload File in PHP

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: why are you looking for another, if this is fulfilling your need ?

Comment: i see your example ,but in this example page is refresh, but i don't want page refresh while image uploading.That's why i'm using jquery

Comment: I think you haven't explored it completely. go here http://malsup.com/jquery/form/progress.html

Comment: okay i use this example but i have one confusion,how can i get request in my controller ,when i'm using $_FILE that so error.

Comment: My friend you need to learn the basics of framework you are using.

Comment: are you getting file in your controller ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ajaxfileupload.js](https://github.com/jfeldstein/jQuery.AjaxFileUpload.js) to upload file:

```
$('input[type="file"]').ajaxfileupload({
          'action': 'save_photo.php',
          'params': {
            'extra': 'info'
          },
          'onComplete': function(response) {

           console.log('custom handler for file:');
           alert(JSON.stringify(response));

          },
          'onStart': function() {               

          },
          'onCancel': function() {
            console.log('no file selected');
          }
    });
```

save_photo.php :

```
<?php

print_r($_FILES); // print details about the file which has been uploaded

?>
```

Comment: This API not work properly .When i am using this API some error display.

Comment: It is working perfectly I have used the same..what error you got?

Comment: When i am using  jquery.ajaxfileupload.js file. i got error message in console  " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  "