# how to display loading .gif while uploading a file in codeIgniter framework

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is my function in controller.I am not using an ajax function to upload data but a **form** **submit** and  I am new to the PHP language.I want to show a loading gif until uploading is finished. I tried searching but found no answers for this framework.

```
try {
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
            $this->load->helper('file');

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('import_attendance', '<br><span style="font-size: 13px;background-color: #FFFFFF;color:#ff0000;border:solid 1px #ff99cc;padding:2px;border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px">No file is Selected</span>');

                redirect('import/drawIndexAttendanceImport');
            } else {

                $upfile = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                $this->load->library('/lib/PHPExcel.php');
                $inputFileName = $upfile['upload_data']['full_path'];  
                $this->load->model('import/import_model');  
$result = $this->import_model->importAttendance($inputFileName);
                if ($result == true) {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('import_attendance', '<br><span style="font-size: 13px;background-color: #FFFFFF;color:#00cc00;border:solid 1px #00cc00;padding:2px;border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px">Succussfully Uploaded </span>');

                    redirect('import/drawIndexAttendanceImport');
                } else {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('import_attendance', '<br><span style="font-size: 13px;background-color: #FFFFFF;color:#ff0000;border:solid 1px #ff99cc;padding:2px;border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px">Upload Error</span>');

                    redirect('import/drawIndexAttendanceImport');
                }
            }
            $this->template->draw('import/drawAttendanceImport', $data);
        } catch (Exception $exc) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: you have to show loading.gif image, until you did not get success msg to image upload.

Comment: for me, this is easier using ajax.

Comment: Steps :: click on upload button show image loading image and run the function saveUpload() This function will save your upload in folder and in db and will return true/false. true if success else false. if true do page refresh.

Comment: Thank you! @Monty, i get it and it is working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If my comment is near to your answer, then i am putting it in answer. is it right ?

Comment: yes it is @Monty. i just used redirect instead of refreshing thank you again.

Comment: @nishz happy to help. dont forget to vote ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suggestion:**

> Steps :: click on upload button show image loading image and run the
>   function saveUpload() This function will save your upload in folder
>   and in db and will return true/false. true if success else false. if
>   true do page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="loadergif">Please place your gif here...</div>
```

Do this when upload starts:
`$("#loadergif").css('display','block');` // to show

Do this on success of img upload:
`$("#loadergif").css('display','none');` // to hide

Note: Do not forgot to hide loader initially.
Helpfull link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/27274616/4229270